# Can’t get a refreshed access_token using spotify api and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, spotify

First time using HTTP Client and Spotify API in Laravel.

The first step is to get a code by visiting
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=c1990...deed3&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.test%2F&scope=user-read-currently-playing%20user-top-read

I then copy the code from the url after being redirected.

Then using curl -

`curl -H "Authorization: Basic YzE5OT...Q2ZjA=" -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=AQBX...X5zg -d redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.test%2F https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`

This returns the refresh token in JSON format -

{
"access_token":"BQBQL...vNDQ",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":3600,
"refresh_token":"AQCy...areM",
"scope":"user-read-currently-playing user-top-read"
}

But then I can't seem to get an access token using the refresh_token.

I'm getting "Bad Request" statusCode: 400 in my app

```php
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Authorization' => `Basic YzE5O...Q2ZjA`,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
])
    ->asForm()
    ->post(
        'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        [
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token' => 'AQC7...YphY'
        ]
    );
```

Here is the documentation https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/.

Has anyone implemented this before in Laravel and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the Spotify API, but I am 99% sure your error is `->asForm()`, you are sending that as a form instead of a normal request... so your code may need to be like this:

```php
$response = Http::withToken('YzE5O...Q2ZjA')
    ->post(
        'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        [
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token' => 'AQC7...YphY'
        ]
    );
```

See that I have removed [`->asForm()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/651b14937e6fa76946b04299d9bfe6f5cc9c8501/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L279-L282) and `Content-Type` (not sure why you are using that, it is a normal API... and `->asForm()` already sets the same content you have manually set...

This is the [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/) and I do not see any need to set the `Conetnt-Type`.

---

My bad, you need to set the `->asForm()`, so the code should be:

```php
$response = Http::withToken('YzE5O...Q2ZjA')
    ->asForm()
    ->post(
        'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        [
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token' => 'AQC7...YphY'
        ]
    );
```

But I still think you are missing something. Check that your `refresh_token` is correct. Also lookf for more debugging output

Comment: Thanks for trying. But I'm getting the same results. I'm definitely missing something.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' was removed from withHeaders

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
  'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . 123...123,
])
->asForm()
->post(
  'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  [
    'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token' => 123...456
  ]
);
```

Comment: Very weird, what I posted as an aswer is exactly the same as your code. `withToken` (on my answer) does exactly `'Authorization' => 'Basic TOKEN'`, same as you did...